# Is there a specific boundary condition in magnetostatics on sharp edges?

Tags: boundary-conditions, magnetostatics

The [magnetostatics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetostatics) [boundary conditions](https://engineering.purdue.edu/wcchew/ece604f19/Lecture%20Notes/Lect4.pdf) states that the parallel field intensity $\mathbf n \times \mathbf H$ and the normal flux density $\mathbf n \cdot \mathbf B$ must be continuous when crossing the boundary from one medium to the other.

Now consider a point that is located on a sharp edge, in this case the normal vector $\mathbf n$ suddenly changes itself. What can we say about the continuity of field on such points?

Another question: Consider we don't cross the boundary and we just move along it. Isn't there any discontinuity in the normal/parallel component of the magnetic field when passing that sharp point?

Comment: Sharp edges in boundary condition (without really giving a definition of "sharp") create singularities in the fields. A completely sharp edge is somewhat unphyisical. So any "real" edge has some sort of rounding, where all the boundary conditions play out as usual.

Comment: Normally one assumes the boundary to be at least differentiable, so you don't run into problems like that.

Comment: @Samuel Of course In real world every edge is smooth, but the problem is in computational modelling.

Comment: @Samuel Can you show how the singularity arises in sharp edges? I mean using the magnetostatics equations.